# Define a function like `%*%` to operate on matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

In R, the function `%*%` is to do matrices multiplication.
For example,

```
A = matrix(c(1,2,1,1), ncol=2)
B = matrix(c(3,0,1,0), ncol=2)
C = A %*% B

A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    1
B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    0    0
C
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    6    2
```

So, C[1, 1] = A[1,1]*B[1,1] + A[1,2]*B[2,1].
Other element of C is also obtained in this way.

The speed of this function is very fast. I guess this function is written in C or C++.

Now, I want to define another function named `%!%` use R so that D = A %!% B.
The desired result of D should be as follow:

```
D = matrix(c(3,1,2,2), ncol=2, byrow=T)
D
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    2    2
```

In which,

```
D[1, 1] = abs(A[1,1]-B[1,1]) + abs(A[1,2]-B[2,1])
```

Other entries of D are calculated in the same way as the 1st entry.

**The formual:**

[image]

The dimensions of A is m by n. The dimensions of B is n by p. And m may equal to n. n may equal to p.

So, how to define this `%!%` function? Currently, I have defined this function using `sapply`. But the speed of my function is much slower than `%*%` and I am wondering if there is any other much more efficient approach.

Here is my definition.

```
`%!%` <- function(A, B) {
  E <- sapply(1:ncol(t(A)), function(x){
    colSums(abs(B - t(A)[,x]), na.rm=TRUE)
  })
  return(t(E))
}
```

Comment: Thx for your info. @李哲源ZheyuanLi

Comment: You have under-specified your function. You have told us what 1 entry is in the 2x2 case, leaving the other 3 entries unspecified and leaving other dimensions undefined. I could probably puzzle it out, but I would prefer if you give a clear definition rather than an example.

Comment: Other entries are calculated in the same way as the 1st entry. See my update. Thx. @JohnColeman

Comment: Sorry, it still isn't clear. Why don't you give a formula involving indices and summations (the way matrix multiplication is typically defined)?

Comment: Ok. wait a min. @JohnColeman

Comment: @VenYao I don't think you understand the issue. You can't just keep saying "the other elements are calculated the same way". Unless you literally want all four elements to be the exact same number always. Your pattern isn't clear from your single example.

Comment: Perhaps you could say that "it is like matrix multiplication but the scalar multiplication in the sums are replaced by the absolute values of the differences"?

Comment: Yes. You got my point. @JohnColeman

Comment: Perhaps you could give your working code. That way someone can `microbenchmark` other solutions

Comment: You could avoid transposing "A" `nrow(A) + 1` times by storing upfront. You could, also, try (if possible) a more memory-consuming approach hoping for any speed gain -- e.g. `matrix(rowSums(abs(A[rep(1:nrow(A), each = ncol(B)), ] - t(B)[rep(1:ncol(B), nrow(A)), ])), nrow(A), ncol(B), byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: Your answer is faster than mine. You should post it as an answer. @alexis_laz

Answer (score 2):

Here is one attempt:

```
sum.abs.dif <- function(u,v){sum(abs(as.vector(u)-as.vector(v)))}

`%!%` <- function(A,B){
  m <- nrow(A)
  n <- ncol(A) #assumed == nrow(A)
  p <- ncol(B)
  indices <- expand.grid(1:m,1:p)
  vals <- apply(indices,1,function(v) sum.abs.dif(A[v[1],],B[,v[2]]))
  matrix(vals,nrow = m)
}
```

For the purpose of comparisons, I took your code and dubbed it `%?%` and then ran a microbenchmark (on your sample `A,B`):

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(A %!% B, A %?% B)
Unit: microseconds
    expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
 A %!% B 180.142 188.813 196.50320 193.7675 198.8990 332.677   100
 A %?% B  43.532  47.602  54.55985  55.0340  57.3345 131.656   100
```

Thus, your code is 4 times as quick as mine. This leads me to suspect that it is unlikely that you will get much more efficient than what you currently have (which of course isn't to say that it can't be improved). `%*%` runs optimized compiled code. Unless you make a C++ extension, you should expect it to be 1 or 2 orders of magnitude quicker than what you have.